# How did '-met' + 'ipse' + '-issimus' compound to mean <the same> (in *metipsimus)?

Tags: etymology, vulgar-latin

> [ [Wiktionary for *metipsimus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/metipsimus) :] **Etymology**
>
> **[0.]** From *[-met](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-met#Latin)* (emphatic suffix) + *[ipse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ipse#Latin)* (“himself”) + *[-issimus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-issimus#Latin)* (superlative suffix).
>
> #### Adjective
>
> ***metipsimus** (*feminine* **[*metipsima](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Latin/metipsima&action=edit&redlink=1)**, *neuter* **[*metipsimum](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Latin/metipsimum&action=edit&redlink=1)**); *[first](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_first_declension)/[second declension](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_second_declension)*
>
> 1. ([Vulgar Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin)) [same](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/same#English)

What semantic notions underlie 0 and 1 above? How did 0 semantically shift to 1? I.e., how does compounding 'himself' with 1 emphatic and 1 superlative suffix generate the meaning of 'same'?

Comment: Doesn't the leading * mean that the word is unattested?

Comment: @Rafael Yes, but the unattested adjective shouldn't affect this question's soundness because it did generate attested cognates.

Comment: @Rafael spot on! Because the question is really about the etymology of French même, which would be considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key to the meaning is *ipse*; all the rest is just intensifiers glommed onto that.

In Classical Latin, *ipse* meant "self"—not as a reflexive, but as an intensive:

> Barack Obaman **ipsum** apud tabernam vīdī!
>   *I saw Barack Obama **himself** at the store!*

This eventually took on a meaning of "same":

> Barack Obaman vīdistī? Praesidentem emeritum?
>   *You saw Barack Obama? The former President?*
>   Ita, **Obaman ipsum**!
>   *Yes, **the very same Obama**!*

The implication, of course, being "the very same person that you're talking about".

But in Vulgar Latin, *ipse* weakened over time. The Latin demonstratives were worn away until their force was lost and they became nothing but articles; *ipse* then lost its intensity and became a normal demonstrative. We see it now in forms like Spanish *ése*, "that".

So when speakers wanted the actual "same" meaning, they had to bring back the intensity. Sometimes they added superlative endings, as in Petronius's *ipsimus*; other times they added the intensive *-met* suffix onto the beginning, from rebracketing *tēmet ipse* "you, you yourself" as **tē metipse*. Eventually they had to combine both to get the proper intensity back, ending up with **metipsimus*.

This is the form that survived into Romance, giving us words like Italian *medesimo* and French *même* < *meïsme*, which can either mean "same" or be a raw intensifier ("very" or "even").

Answer (score 3):

Like Draconis stated, it's the weakening of the original word that caused it to be a demonstrative to fill the void that *ille* and *iste* left. It's similar to what happened in our language, "the" was originally a demonstrative as well in Old English, but weakened to merely a definite article totally in Middle English.

I believe the addition of the meaning "same" was the result of *īdem* falling out of favor in colloquial speech, so *metipsimus* filled that void as well. In Spanish, "mismo", it's cognate, can be used to mean both.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for the nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

The Vulgar Latin *metipsimus*, as a contraction of older *metipsissimus*, a superlative of *metipse*, comes from a reanalysis of *egomet ipse* "me myself" as *ego metipse*. In Latin, **-met** was attached to pronouns, but in Vulgar Latin it was reanalyzed as part of *ipse* instead.